# Double call to root path "/" in a website

Tags: security, http, website, root, performance-monitoring

I'm checking my web page performance, but some strange reason it double calls to root path.

[image: Description]

Any idea why this is happening?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I access your site with the command line tool `curl` rather than a proper browser I get the error message:

> **Access Denied**
> **vde.com.mx** is using a security service for protection against online attacks. An action has triggered the service and blocked your request.
>
> Please try again in a few minutes. If the issue persist, please contact the site owner for further assistance.
>
> Protected by `https://www.stackpath.com`

When accessing your site with a proper browser it will be displayed after a little delay. I expect that said service is the cause of your observations.

Comment: I do a curl from command line; and it works. How do you get that?